# Проблема с вводом и выводом чисел

Tags: c#, массивы, консоль, вывод

Не совсем понимаю, как реализовать последовательный ввод пользователем чисел, которые после выводятся в массив, вследствие чего пользователь в итоге должен получить наименьшее значение в массиве, которое он ввёл.

Думал реализовать через:

```
int N;
int[] nums = new int[N];
```

Чтобы вышло нечто вот такое:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int min_numb = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Привет!");
            Console.WriteLine("Введи последовательно все числа, которые нужны в наборе.");
            Console.WriteLine("Как только будут введены все числа, введите [done] чтобы завершить ввод");
            Console.WriteLine("Либо [exit] чтобы выйти из приложения");

            //вот здесь должно быть построение этого списка

            //сборка всех чисел в массив

            string selection = Console.ReadLine(); //тут уже команды выйти или завершить ввод и выбрать наименьшее число в массиве
            switch (selection)
            {
                case "done":
                    Console.WriteLine("Отлично, тогда провожу вычисления...");
                    //ищем из массива наименьшее значение
                    int[] массив = { 1, 2, 4, 6, 15, 32 };
                    Console.WriteLine(массив.Min());
                    Console.ReadKey();

                    Console.WriteLine($"Минимальное число тут: {min_numb}");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    break;

                case "exit":
                    Console.WriteLine("Программа завершена");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть пользователь вводит числа через пробел. Потом вы можете их сохранить в строку, спарсить в целочисленные значения и добавить в массив. Это если я вас правильно понял.

Answer (score 1):

Вот процесс ввода чисел. Если я правильно понял, ты не знаешь, как ввести их динамически.

```
List<int> mass = new List<int>(); //объявляем лист для динамического добавления новых элементов
while(true) //бесконечный цикл
{
    string s = Console.ReadLine();//читаем что написал юзер
    if(s == "done") break; // если написал "done", то прекращаем работу цикла
    try
    {
        mass.Add(Convert.ToInt32(s)); // добавляем цифру в лист
    }
    catch(Exception ex) //если юзер ввёл не цифру
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); //мы его об этом уведомляем
        Console.WriteLine("Продолжить (continue) или Закончить (end)"); //предлагаем ввести (continue) или (end)
        if(Console.ReadLine() == "end") break; //если (end), то завершаем работу цикла
        else continue; // в ином случае продолжаем работу цикла
    }           
}
int[] arr = mass.ToArray(); // преобразуем лист в массив
```

Ну либо, как вариант, как тебе предложили другие. Попроси пользователя вводить числа через пробел, запятую или другие символы и потом воспользуйся функцией Split

```
 int[] mass = Console.ReadLine() // читаем весь набор чисел
             .Split(' ') // делим на массив строк по символу пробела, можно и другой ввести
             .Select(item => Convert.ToInt32(item)) // преобразуем каждый элемент массива в int
             .ToArray() // преобразуем объект в массив
```